# openshift and bad request after deploying django 1.6

Tags: python, django, deployment, openshift

I created a django app using openshifts default django quickstart app. But because it is based on django 1.4 I did the following changes

setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='YourAppName',
    version='1.0',
    description='OpenShift App',
    author='Your Name',
    author_email='example@example.com',
    url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
    install_requires=['Django==1.6'],# changed this from Django <= 1.4
)
```

to instruct openshift to install Django 1.6. I also changed my manage.py to the one that Django 1.6 uses. I deployed it and I got a success message. But when visiting my web page it gives me a bad request.

directory tree

```
wsgi
├── application
├── beta_tree.txt
├── openshift
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── manage.py~
│   ├── openshiftlibs.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.py~
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── sqlite3.db
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── home
│   │       └── home.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── static
    └── README
```

settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Django settings for OpenShift project.
import imp, os

# a setting to determine whether we are running on OpenShift
ON_OPENSHIFT = False
if os.environ.has_key('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'):
    ON_OPENSHIFT = True

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DEBUG', False))
    if DEBUG:
        print("WARNING: The DEBUG environment is set to True.")
else:
    DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    # os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_*'] variables can be used with databases created
    # with rhc cartridge add (see /README in this git repo)
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'], 'sqlite3.db'),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'sqlite3.db'),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR', '')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '..', 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
#ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make a dictionary of default keys
default_keys = { 'SECRET_KEY': 'secret_key' }

# Replace default keys with dynamic values if we are in OpenShift
use_keys = default_keys
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    imp.find_module('openshiftlibs')
    import openshiftlibs
    use_keys = openshiftlibs.openshift_secure(default_keys)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = use_keys['SECRET_KEY']

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'openshift.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)


WSGI_APPLICATION = "wsgi.application"

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

I remember it being easier to deploy.

Comment: Well it seems that the quick start application from openshift doesn't include the ALLOWED_HOSTS in the settings file...Once uploaded everything works fine